# coerce column names from column factors and populate

Tags: r, multiple-columns, coercion

I have data like

```
set.seed(6)
df <- data.frame(t = as.Date("2014/1/1")+seq(0,100.25,.25),
    name = paste(sample(c("Alert_","NonOp_"),402,replace=TRUE),
                  sample(1:10,402,replace=TRUE),sep=""),
    unit = c(rep(1:10,each=40),10,10))
head(df)
```

Here is some representative data

```
head(df)
            t     name   unit
1  2014-01-01  NonOp_3      1
2  2014-01-01  NonOp_6      1
3  2014-01-01  Alert_5      1
4  2014-01-01  Alert_7      1
5  2014-01-02  NonOp_4      1
6  2014-01-02  NonOp_2      1
```

How to generate a table from the names, where the table has columns of unit, t, and then names in the name column gets coerced into columns of name factored without the Alert/NonOp, and the values in the factored names columns should be NA, A (for alert), and N (for NonOp).  Here is the type of table I'm looking for, if all the numbers above were for unit 1.

```
unit               t   name_1 name_2 name_3 name_4 name_5 name_6 name_7 name_8 ...
   1      2014-01-01       NA     NA      N     NA      A      A      A     NA
   1      2014-01-02       NA      N     NA      N     NA     NA     NA     NA
```

The goal is to the named alerts / nonops into a table ordered by unit / t and write the table to a file.  And read the file into excel.

Comment: Please use `set.seed` when posting example code using `sample`.

Comment: Also, your example `df <- ...` does not produce the data you show in `head(df)`

Comment: I think you're looking for the `dcast` function in `reshape2`.  Try `library(reshape2); dcast(df, unit + t ~ name)`

Comment: added set.seed, and updated the table to be consistent with the data

Comment: @maloneypatr thanks, not quite right, but I can go with that.

Comment: @user3969377 - It still wasn't right.  I fixed it.  Please note the differences in output.

Comment: OK, with dcast, I need to make the line a lot longer so the lines don't wrap, there are 150 values for name, and the names are long.  Also, the file ends with [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 68305 rows ].

Comment: @RichardScriven, thanks, it's been a long day, and I'm trying to get this to the next person...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It *sounds* like the following is what you're looking for:

```
library(reshape2)
newdf <- cbind(df, colsplit(df$name, "_", c("V1", "V2")))
newdf$V1 <- factor(newdf$V1, c("NonOp", "Alert"), c("N", "A"))
newdf$V2 <- paste0("name_", newdf$V2)
head(newdf)
#            t    name unit V1     V2
# 1 2014-01-01 NonOp_3    1  N name_3
# 2 2014-01-01 NonOp_6    1  N name_6
# 3 2014-01-01 Alert_5    1  A name_5
# 4 2014-01-01 Alert_7    1  A name_7
# 5 2014-01-02 NonOp_4    1  N name_4
# 6 2014-01-02 NonOp_2    1  N name_2

head(dcast(newdf, t ~ V2, value.var = "V1"))
#            t name_1 name_10 name_2 name_3 name_4 name_5 name_6 name_7 name_8 name_9
# 1 2014-01-01   <NA>    <NA>   <NA>      N   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
# 2 2014-01-01   <NA>    <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>      N   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
# 3 2014-01-01   <NA>    <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>      A   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
# 4 2014-01-01   <NA>    <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>      A   <NA>   <NA>
# 5 2014-01-02   <NA>    <NA>   <NA>   <NA>      N   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
# 6 2014-01-02   <NA>    <NA>      N   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
```

Basically, start by splitting the "name" column into two columns, and then use `dcast`. The other steps are mostly cosmetic.

---

Another approach would be to use [my `cSplit` function](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/11380733/) and `dcast.data.table` from the "data.table" package.

Skipping things like creating "name_blah" and replacing "NonOp" with "N" and so on, you can just directly do:

```
dcast.data.table(cSplit(df, "name", "_"), t ~ name_2, value.var = "name_1")
#               t     1 10     2     3     4     5     6     7  8  9
#   1: 2014-01-01    NA NA    NA NonOp    NA    NA    NA    NA NA NA
#   2: 2014-01-01    NA NA    NA    NA    NA    NA NonOp    NA NA NA
#   3: 2014-01-01    NA NA    NA    NA    NA Alert    NA    NA NA NA
#   4: 2014-01-01    NA NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA Alert NA NA
#   5: 2014-01-02    NA NA    NA    NA NonOp    NA    NA    NA NA NA
#  ---                                                              
# 398: 2014-04-10    NA NA    NA    NA    NA    NA NonOp    NA NA NA
# 399: 2014-04-10    NA NA    NA    NA NonOp    NA    NA    NA NA NA
# 400: 2014-04-10 NonOp NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA NA NA
# 401: 2014-04-11    NA NA    NA NonOp    NA    NA    NA    NA NA NA
# 402: 2014-04-11    NA NA Alert    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA NA NA
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
res <- df %>% 
separate(name, c("V1", "V2")) %>%
mutate(V1=substr(V1, 1, 1), V2 =paste0("name_", V2)) %>%
select(-unit) %>% 
spread(key=V2, value=V1) 

library(gtools)
res1 <- res[,c(1,mixedorder(names(res)[-1])+1)]
 head(res1,2)
  #         t name_1 name_2 name_3 name_4 name_5 name_6 name_7 name_8 name_9
 #1 2014-01-01   <NA>   <NA>      N   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
 #2 2014-01-01   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>      N   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
 # name_10
 #1    <NA>
 #2    <NA>
```